# Fermions and Bosons

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fermions, bosons

For fermions $$P-\frac{Nk_BT}{V}\geq 0 $$ and for bosons, $$P-\frac{Nk_BT}{V}\leq 0$$ What can we understand from these results.

Comment: maybe you can quote the sources where you found these results?

Comment: I just proved it myself by using the Grand Partition function for bosons and fermions. I don't know the exact source, but I think Huang's book has the above result shown.

Comment: It would probably be useful if you could show us your initial assumptions and some key steps, in order for us to be able to reproduce it and spot any mistakes

Comment: You are presumably talking about *non-interacting* particles? Are your expressions related to the chemical potential?

Comment: Yes,the particles are non-interacting. My expressions are not quite related to chemical potential.

Answer (score 5):

Essentially you're deriving varients on the [ideal gas law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law):

$$ PV = nkT $$

The ideal gas law falls out when your system of particles obeys a Boltzmann distribution. From this you can derive the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution of velocities and from that the pressure.

If your system contains bosons then it will obey [Bose-Einstein statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_statistics) and compared to the Boltzmann distribution it will be weighted towards the low energy end so the pressure will work out lower. If your system contains fermions it will obey [Fermi-Dirac statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics) and compared to the Boltzmann distribution it will be weighted towards the high energy end so the pressure will work out higher.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add some mathematical details to the answers and comments here: in the context of ideal gases we can write
$$P=\frac{kT}{aV}\sum_{\varepsilon}\ln(1+aze^{-\beta \varepsilon})$$
where the parameter $a$ is equal to $0$ for the Maxwell-Boltzmann ($MB$) statistics and $-1, +1$ respectively for the Bose-Einstein ($BE$) and the Fermi-Dirac ($FD$) statistics.
Every statistics has a different weight factor $g\{n_{\varepsilon}\}$ (here we are dealing with single particle states), namely
$$g_{MB}\{n_{\varepsilon}\}=\prod_{\varepsilon}\frac{1}{n_{\varepsilon}!} \hspace{1 cm} g_{BE}\{n_{\varepsilon}\}=1 \hspace{1 cm} g_{FD}\{n_{\varepsilon}\}=\cases{1 \ \text{if all $n_{\varepsilon}=0,1$}\\ 0 \ \text{otherwise}}$$
which give rise to different expressions for the grand-canonical partition functions
$$Q_{MB}=\exp(zV/\lambda^3)\hspace{1 cm} Q_{BE}=\prod_{\varepsilon}\frac{1}{1-ze^{-\beta \varepsilon}} \hspace{1 cm} Q_{FD}=\prod_{\varepsilon}(1+ze^{-\beta \varepsilon})$$
I have reported these expressions here in case one wants to verify the previous expression for the pressure.
In the expression of $P$, the volume $V$ is always considered to be sufficiently large to allow the summation over $\varepsilon$ to be replaced by an integral over $d\varepsilon$ using a proper density of states $\rho(\varepsilon)=\frac{2\pi V}{h^3}(2m)^{3/2}\varepsilon^{1/2}$. Moreover, it can be useful to make a change of variable using the linear momenta of the particles $\varepsilon=p^2/2m$. One gets
$$P=\frac{4\pi}{3 \hbar^3}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^{-1}e^{\beta p^2/2m}+a}\left(\frac{p^2}{m}\right)p^2 \ dp$$
Then, one can also calculate the number of particles $N=\int \rho(\varepsilon)d\varepsilon$ in the system
$$N=\frac{4\pi V}{\hbar^3}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^{-1}e^{\beta p^2/2m}+a}p^2 \ dp$$
These two expression lead to a useful relation between pressure and energy:
$$P=\frac{1}{3}\frac{N}{V}\left\langle \frac{p^2}{m}\right\rangle=\frac{2}{3}\frac{E}{V}$$
where the brakets $\langle ...\rangle$ stand for an ensemble average. This relation is totally independent of the parameter $a$ and tells us that the pressure of the ideal gas arises essentially from the motion of its particles. One can now use the energy expressions and make a comparison
$$E_{MB}=\frac{3}{2}NkT \hspace{1 cm} E_{BE}=\frac{3}{2}(N-N_0)kT\frac{g_{5/2}(z)}{g_{3/2}(z)} \hspace{1 cm}E_{FD}=\frac{3}{2}NkT\frac{f_{5/2}(z)}{f_{3/2}(z)}$$
where $g_{\nu}(z)$ (with $0\le z<1$) and $f_{\nu}(z)$ (with $0\le z<\infty$) are respectively the Bose-Einstein functions and Fermi-Dirac functions. The term $N_0$ here stands for the number of particles in the ground state which constitute the condensed phase of the Bose-Einstein gas. One can prove that $E_{BE}<E_{MB}<E_{FD}$ for every value of $z$ belonging to its statistical range. Here I just want to give a simple example: let us take $z=1$ (in the BE case $z$ assumes the value of $1$ only asymptotically in the case in which $N, N_0\rightarrow \infty$). We have
$$ g_{\nu}(1)=\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{l^{\nu}}=\zeta(\nu)\\
f_{\nu}(1)=\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{l-1}}{l^{\nu}}=(1-2^{1-\nu})\zeta(\nu)$$
where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function. Given the values $\zeta(3/2)\simeq 2.62$ and $\zeta(5/2)\simeq 1.34$ one can verify that $g_{5/2}(1)<g_{3/2}(1)$ and $f_{5/2}(1)>f_{3/2}(1)$, thus the condition $E_{BE}<E_{MB}<E_{FD}$ is respected. In conclusion, at fixed volume, one can write $P_{BE}<\frac{NkT}{V}<P_{FD}$. The equality holds in the case in which $T\rightarrow \infty$. Physically speaking, the relation $\frac{NkT}{V}<P_{FD}$ is basically due to the Pauli principle which states that no quantum state can be occupied by more than one fermion, this prevents the formation of a condensed state and keeps the fermions separated from each other. On the other hand the relation $P_{BE}<\frac{NkT}{V}$ reflects the fact that an ideal gas of bosons forms a condensate at $T<T_c$ (with $T_c$ called critical temperature), unlike a classical ideal gas.